# The [programmatically] tag needs some lovin'

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, the [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programmatically) tag's usage guidance states:

> Do not use this tag: it doesn't add meaningful information to a question, as "programmatically" could apply to most programming questions.

And there's no wiki info.

There are 249 questions with the tag (there were more but a user has been purging its use of late).

I suggest that in certain other tags, the [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programmatically) tag can help disambiguate a question. I focus on the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag and in many cases a user interface related question can be based on a code-only implementation or it can be based on using a storyboard (kind of a drag-n-drop GUI builder in the Xcode IDE).

If the user's question is related to building the user interface via storyboard, there is the [storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storyboard) tag. For code-only user interface related questions, the [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programmatically) tag helps make it clear that a storyboard-related answer is not desired.

So should the [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programmatically) tag be brought back to life with more useful usage guidance, or should the tag be laid to rest?

Comment: I don't agree with this. Any good Cocoa question should have at least two answers; one doing it programmatically, and one doing it in the UI files. It shouldn't be tagged into the question.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship While ultimately answers of both type can prove useful to other users, the OP is looking for only one or the other. If I ask how to do some UI work using only code, if 5 answers appear all showing storyboard screenshots, it doesn't do me any good.

Comment: Well, a question is not supposed to only be useful to the asker. If that's the case, the question serves no purpose on Stack Overflow. It's better they write an explicit request in the question, which is then later edited out, or specify this particular need in a comment.

Comment: Some analysis of how the tag is being used (or misused) would be helpful. If the tag is mostly being applied to questions which it adds no benefit to, then even if there are some questions where the tag might make sense, it's unlikely anyone is using the tag to find those questions.

Comment: This combination of tags seems rather arcane. *Any* question on SO should be programming related (even if programmed via a gui) and have some programmatic content or context. A generic name such as `programmaric` doesn’t give any indication what’s it for, with which tags it should be used, and especially not how it should not be used.

Comment: I agree with the others - the `programmatically` tag simply adds ambiguity and fluff to the question tags. @MisterMiyagi - Completely agree.

Comment: "If the user's question is related to building the user interface via storyboard, there is the storyboard tag." - No; the storyboard tag **is not for** questions about building a UI via storyboard, because someone who does so is **not writing code** and therefore does **not have an on-topic question**. Unless, of course, the storyboard aspect is only incidental to a larger context that does involve writing code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's a rather strange claim to state that a programming question about using a programming tool is off-topic.

Comment: If the overall solution is codeless, it is not a programming question, and the tool is being used in a way that is demonstrably accessible to non-programmers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that tag should not exist at all.

> ...the [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programmatically) tag can help disambiguate a question.

I think your logic is in reverse.

By default, *any* on-topic question on this site should *already* be about how to *programmatically* accomplish a certain task/algorithm/goal/objective. That normally involves creating a program and writing some code. Since questions about writing code require the tag for the programming language/s being used, the language tag alone is more than enough to indicate that the goal is to programmatically do something. Therefore, for most cases, adding a [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programmatically) tag is just plain redundant.

Now, of course, not every question is about literally writing code. Stack Overflow accepts questions about using "software tools" as long as it is a "practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". For those questions, the necessary tag would be the tag for *that* specific tool. In your example about iOS, if the question is specifically about using a storyboard, then it should be tagged with [storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storyboard)<sup>1</sup>. So a question with both [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storyboard) already helps in disambiguating it from other questions that are tagged, for example, with [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift).

Furthermore, if somehow the question is still on-topic but not requiring a programmatic solution (for example, it is about creating a YAML config file), then the question should *clearly* describe and indicate that that is the case, like "how do I do X by defining it in a YAML file?" In those cases, the logic is in reverse to what you are describing: the disambiguation should be done by the *non-programmatic* cases.

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't lurk around the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag anymore, so a better tag or tag combination might be used.

Comment: Good thoughts. I'm convinced.