# The [programmatically] tag won't automatically delete

Tags: bug, status-review, tags

A while ago I noticed that the [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programmatically) description said:

> Do not use this tag: it doesn't add meaningful information to a question, as "programmatically" could apply to most programming questions.

All the questions with the tag were cleaned up, agreeing with [this MSO answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424486/). However, I've waited for several days now, and the tag is still showing that it has 1 question when I hover over it. Same symptoms as reported in [Let's say bye bye to [hello]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421664/), but I'm not sure if it's caused by the exact same bug.

Is there still some draft article or "ghost" question that needs to be deleted to clean up this tag?

Comment: About a year ago (maybe longer) a bug was introduced that broke the tag removal process for random tags that no longer had 0 undeleted questions. This is probably suffering from that same bug. AFAIK there's no reliable way for users or even moderators to deal with it. I think it requires a CM or dev to truly fix, and it's a per-tag fix until the underlying bug gets addressed.

Comment: It might be that it can't be cleaned up since it has a synonym. I know there's an exception for tags with 0 posts being retained if they are a synonym of an existing tag. I'll try removing the synonym to see if that allows the task to clean it up.

Comment: So I'm still keeping an eye on this... but it, indeed, appears to the same issue as before or at least not related to the synonym. I've marked this as [status-review] so someone with access can confirm against article drafts or track down the issue in the event it's not the same as before